# Cyrillic font on MS sql server and tfpdf

Tags: php, sql-server, fpdf, cyrillic

I have a problem with the cyrillic fonts.
The user inserts some data in a MS SQL database and the data are well saved in the database in a `nvarchar` column. I mean that I can see the cyrillic fonts using a sql client like `heideSQL` in my case.
When I use echo with `php` or I try to print out a pdf document with `tFPDF` I see just ????????.
On the web browser I see cyrillic fonts without any problems.

Any suggestions?

here the code:

$sql="select text from table where user='xxxxxxx'";

$result=sqlsrv_query($db_conn, $sql);

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['text'].'
';
}

and this is the result:

Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚ 4
Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚ 4
Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚ 4
Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚ 4
Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚ 4

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are `cyrillic fonts` supported by tFPDF?

Comment: Yes. http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php . you can see an example here http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/ex92.pdf.

Comment: Can you share the PHP code that returns *???????*?

Comment: When `echo` in php try use `mb_convert_encoding` for that cell. Try `windows-1251` to `UTF-8` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mea culpa:

to see the correct fonts on the browser is sufficient to intert this at the top of the page:

meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"

the result on the browser is this:

string: тест 5
encoding: UTF-8
string: тест 4
encoding: UTF-8
string: тест 4
encoding: UTF-8
string: тест 4
encoding: UTF-8
string: тест 4
encoding: UTF-8
string: тест 4
encoding: UTF-8

in the script there was an old query with an datatype conversion:

convert (TEXT, ...)

The TEXT datatype is deprecated. The solution was to convert it to NVARCHAR

convert (NVARCHAR, ...)

And also tFPDF works great.